# UISelectBoolean isSelected() always returns false regardless of state of checkbox

Tags: jsf

I have the following block of HTML:

```html
<div data-enhance="false">
  <label for="qc_20012" data-iconpos="right">Text</label>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input id="qc_20012" type="checkbox" name="qc_20012">
    <label for="qc_20012"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I simply want to extract the state of the checkbox (`isSelected` true/false) using Java as seen below:

```
//id is the id of the HTML input (in this case, qc_20012)
UIComponent uiComponent = findComponent(id);
if (uiComponent instanceof UISelectBoolean) {
    UISelectBoolean comp = (UISelectBoolean) uiComponent;
    //always prints out 'false'
    System.out.println(comp.isSelected());
}
```

Here's `findComponent`. To be honest I don't really understand what's going on in there, so it's likely that this is where the problem lays. I've tried digging deeper but everything appears correct in there to me:

```
private UIComponent findComponent(final String id) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
    final UIComponent[] found = new UIComponent[1];
    root.visitTree(new FullVisitContext(context), new VisitCallback() {
            @Override
            public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent component) {
                if (component.getId() != null && component.getId().equals(id)) {
                    found[0] = component;
                    return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
                }
                return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
            }
        });
    return found[0];
}
```

No matter what, the `comp.isSelected()` line prints out `false`. Doesn't matter if the checkbox is checked, unchecked, or not on the page.

Here's the actual JSF that starts the chain that ends up calling this code:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
                       value="#{cc.attrs.label}"
                       onclick="#{cc.attrs.onclick}"
                       data="#{cc.attrs.data}"
                       onbegin="#{cc.attrs.onbegin}"
                       onbeforedomupdate="#{cc.attrs.onbeforedomupdate}"
                       oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.oncomplete}"
                       immediate="#{cc.attrs.immediate}"
                       render="#{cc.attrs.render}"
                       execute="#{cc.attrs.execute}"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Facelets nor JSF code at all. Please provide the JSF/Facelets code to replicate the problem.

Comment: This part of the project is manipulating the JSF at a Java level. For instance, javax.faces.component.UIComponentis.UISelectBoolean is the class I'm trying to manipulate. For whatever reason, the author of the code chose this approach.

Comment: When do you execute the code to retrieve `comp.isSelected()`? Looks like you execute it before the apply request values phase.

Comment: It happens after a form is submitted via POST. I'm not sure what the "apply values" phase is, but I would think that this would be after it. However, I'm very new to JSF and just inherited this code so I'm not exactly sure how to tell.

Comment: Provide the code that executes/fires this functionality. More info: [JSF lifecycle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_life_cycle.htm) and [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) (I recommend the latter more than the former).

Comment: Edited the question. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Also thanks for the links, I'll check them out.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Now you have to provide the client since looks like this `<a4j:commandButton>` is part of a composite component.

Comment: Looks like a4j is a third party library: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/a4j/commandButton.html

Comment: I know that component is from RichFaces. The fact you're using `#{cc.attrs.foo}` means that you have a composite component and inside it uses this RichFaces component. What I'm asking you now to provide a better analysis of the problem is where is this composite component being used and how.

Answer (score -1):

Since the checkbox component you are using is not a JSF component it is not available in JSF component tree. So it cannot be found in `findComponent()` method. Replace the line

> <input id="qc_20012" type="checkbox" name="qc_20012"/>

with

> <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="qc_20012" name="qc_20012"/>

and it will work.